# is const { propName as newName } = object or similar possible?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to get an object property but as a different name

This works for the same name: `const { propertyName } = object`

**but I would like to use
`const { propertyName as newPropertyName } = object`**

This doesn't work, is this another way to do it? I've seen javascript imports work this way.

Comment: `const { actualName : newName } = object;`

Comment: that worked, thank you!